# Entity Reference Views - Contextual Filters - Administrator override

Tags: views, entities

I have an Entity reference field View with contextual filter with Logged in user ID . The result of this view could be seen by the user only if he/she added some data. That is fine.

I would like to use the same Entity reference field View, so that administrator can view all the results without any restriction.

How can we achieve this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why this works but anyways.. It seems to be what you want.

You'll need [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or).

In my test, I used the contextual filter for author UID. So your entity reference field would only shows nodes created by the current user.

1. In your view, add the `Content: Author` relationship (don't check required) and `Content: Author uid` contextual filter (provide default: current user).
2. Enable `Contextual filters OR` in Query settings under Advanced.
3. Add a second contextual filter for `Content: Author uid` (provide default: current user)
4. Under *More* at the bottom of the filter, click **exclude**.

When added this an entity reference field, normal users only see nodes they've created but as admin, I see every node on the site. Weird but it works.

Comment: Thanks. But when I create Entity Reference View, I cant see the Query settings under Advanced .

Comment: Did you install the module?

Comment: yes. and enabled.

Comment: I can see the module in query settings when the view is normal. But NOT when its Entity Reference View.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 I was able to do this without any contrib module like contextual filters OR.

1. add the Authored By contextual filter for your entity type
2. choose provide default value... from logged in user
3. below in the "when value provided" section select "specify validation criteria
4. For validator select User ID
5. check "restrict user based on role"
6. select your NON-ADMIN roles
7. for "Action to take if filter value does not validate" select "display all results"

So if viewed by the non-admins is will show only where the logged in user id matches the entity owner. For admins it will show all.